# torch tensor object error while using bayesian for market mix modeling

Tags: pytorch, theano, pymc

I am developing a MMM project which uses the below adstock transformation function using torch:

```
def adstock_geometric_pytensor(x, theta):
    x = torch.tensor(x,dtype=torch.float32)
    theta = torch.tensor(theta, dtype=torch.float32)
    
    def adstock_geometric_recurrence_pytensor(index, input_x, decay_x, theta):
        decay_x[index] = input_x + theta * decay_x[index-1]
        return decay_x

    len_observed = x.shape[0]

    x_decayed = torch.zeros_like(x)
    x_decayed[0] = x[0]

    for index in range(1,len_observed):
        x_decayed[index] = adstock_geometric_recurrence_pytensor(index,x[index],x_decayed,theta)
    
    return x_decayed
```

This is futher used down below while defining the model priors:

```
%%time

transform_variables = ["trend", "season", "holiday", 'Audio_s','Cable_s']
    
delay_channels = ['Audio_s','Cable_s']
media_channels = ['Audio_s','Cable_s']
control_variables = ["trend", "season", "holiday"]

target = "Joins"

data_transformed = final_data.copy()

numerical_encoder_dict = {}

for feature in transform_variables:
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    original = final_data[feature].values.reshape(-1, 1)
    transformed = scaler.fit_transform(original)
    data_transformed[feature] = transformed
    numerical_encoder_dict[feature] = scaler

dependent_transformation = None
original = final_data[target].values
data_transformed[target] = original 

# #Model 1:
response_mean = []
with pm.Model() as model_2:
    for channel_name in delay_channels:
        
        print(f"Delay Channels: Adding {channel_name}")
        
        x = data_transformed[channel_name].values
        
        adstock_param = pm.Beta(f"{channel_name}_adstock",3,3)
        pidata = pm.sample(1000,random_seed=43)
        adstock_param = np.average(pidata.posterior[f"{channel_name}_adstock"].to_numpy().flatten())
        
        saturation_gamma = pm.Beta(f"{channel_name}_gamma",2,2)
        pidata = pm.sample(1000,random_seed=43)
        saturation_gamma = np.average(pidata.posterior[f"{channel_name}_gamma"].to_numpy().flatten())
        
        saturation_alpha = pm.Beta(f"{channel_name}_alpha",3,1)
        pidata = pm.sample(1000,random_seed=43)
        saturation_alpha = np.average(pidata.posterior[f"{channel_name}_alpha"].to_numpy().flatten())
        
        
        x_new = adstock_geometric_pytensor(x, adstock_param)
        x_new_sliced = x_new[START_ANALYSIS_INDEX:END_ANALYSIS_INDEX]
        saturation_tensor = saturation_hill_pymc(x_new_sliced, saturation_alpha, saturation_gamma)
```

However this gives me the below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File <timed exec>:51

Cell In[67], line 47, in adstock_geometric_pytensor(x, theta)
     44 x_decayed[0] = x[0]
     46 for index in range(1,len_observed):
---> 47     x_decayed[index] = adstock_geometric_recurrence_pytensor(index,x[index],x_decayed,theta)
     49 return x_decayed

RuntimeError: expand(torch.FloatTensor{[365]}, size=[]): the number of sizes provided (0) must be greater or equal to the number of dimensions in the tensor (1)
```

Not sure what is causing the error, is it the function adstock_geometric_pytensor or the way I am defining the priors under pm.Model()

If someone has experience into market mix modeling with adstock transformations using pymc latest version which doesn't use Theano anymore, can he/she kindly guide me here.